# Does my MacBook Pro (2016) supports CUDA?

Tags: macbook-pro, macos

I have MacBook Pro with maximum specifications and mostly I use for video rendering stuff. The performance is great but I found that I could make video rendering a lot faster by enabling CUDA.

I explore some sites and found that CUDA works with NVidia Graphics and there are many similar questions but there is a slight difference in model (like Graphic card).

So, can anyone please confirm:

- if my MACBook supports CUDA?
- if not, what is the best alternative?

**MacBook Info:**

- **Model:** MacBook Pro (15-inch, 2016)
- **Graphic:**

  1. Intel HD Graphics 530 (1536MB)
  2. AMD Radeon Pro 460 (4096MB)

**PS:** Many people recommends to check GPU support on this link: https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-gpus As it's on NVidia website so I am not sure if they are listing all supported OR just NVidia all supported gpus.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

CUDA is a NVIDIA technology and only exists on NVIDIA graphics cards. Your MacBook Pro has an AMD graphics card and therefore doesn't support CUDA.

Comment: thanks and is there any alternative available?

Comment: @Alena The AMD equivalent of CUDA is [OpenCL](https://www.khronos.org/opencl/), plus there's Apple's [Metal](https://developer.apple.com/metal/). This is what makes FCPX far more optimised than Adobe Premiere on Macs.